# Google script notifies all email adresses everytime the script runs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way to make it so you do not send a notification to the user's email when using addEditor(email) on Google script. Been looking through the references for Google developers and haven't found anything.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1aU3MOdUKHEgGRCtVaSJs3iRqRIRhLSvpCuXzOVT7Ko8")
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ark 1")
var range = sheet.getRange("B:C")
//Column B is the emails, and C is a list of Edit, View, None

var range_length = range.getValues().length + 1

function scriptTesting(row) {
  var scriptTesting = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8FOoqX6_Y84eHZFaFBGTlJzMTQ")
  
  for (var a = 1; range_length > a; a++) {
     var email = range.getCell(a, 1).getValue()
     var choice = range.getCell(a, 2).getValue()
     
     if (choice == "Edit") {
     scriptTesting.addEditor(email)
     } else if (choice == "View") {
     scriptTesting.addViewer(email)
     } else if (email == "") {
     break
     } else if (choice == "None") {
       try {
       scriptTesting.removeViewer(email)
       } catch(err) {
         continue
       }
     } else {
     continue
     }
     }

}
```

Comment: you can use advanced drive services, see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287096/addeditors-through-advanced-drive-service-without-notification-emails/37289790#37289790

Comment: Thank you for the help. Did not find this before.

Comment: When would you like to notify or send an email to your recipient? And is there any other reason you would like to run this app than to notifying your recipient? If you intend to use the App for testing purpose, I would just add one or two e-mails of myself to the addEditor.